# Why is kibana timelion timing out on the same query that succeeds in "discover"?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I am using ElasticSearch 5.5 and I'm trying to create a timelion visualization through kibana.

when I input the following into timelion with "last 15 minutes" as my time range:

```
.es(timefield='packet_timestamp',index=my-idx*,q=sortfield:sortvalue)
```

I get a timeout in the form of:

```
Timelion: Error: in cell #1: Request Timeout after 30000ms.
```

However, If I go to the "discover" tab, select my-idx* from the index patterns, put sortfield:sortvalue in the search bar with the same time range, data populates almost instantly.

Why is timelion timing out on the same query as the discover function?